# Unable to download app for enterprise distribution while using shared extension

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode8, codesign, ios8-share-extension

I have an app which contains share extension. I had created separate provisioning profile and bundle id for shared extension, also enabled app group for both app id. I am submitting app to inhouse develovment, it is submitted successfully, when I trying install that app it shows error `Unable to download app could not be installed at this time`

> While I seen the device log it shows error: App with identifier is already installed, so we can't install App Extension with that same identifier.

how to resolve this issue, thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Guessing from the error message, you may have a problem with the CFBundleIdentifier of your extension: you may already have an app installed on the same device with that exact same CFBundleIdentifier.

Solution: try using another Identifier and be 100% sure that the new one is unique.